# AWS IAM create access key failure

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Having trouble creating an access key for my AWS user. I've set up aws on the command line (aws configure) and try the following command

```
aws iam create-access-key --user-name myUser
```

I get the following response and have no clue what to do. Seems to be a problem with python or something from my quick google

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```

Comment: Have you provided an Access Key and Secret Key for use with the AWS CLI (via the `aws configure` command)? Are you running this from your own computer or from EC2?

Comment: I did use `aws configure` with the access key id and the access secret. I'm running from my own computer

Comment: Try following (the working) example at https://gist.github.com/garnaat/2917662.

Comment: FYI, your syntax worked fine for me.